# Fullscreen flickering while in-game

Tags: project-64

While using Project 64 in-game, when I go to Fullscreen, my game flickers. Someone said it had something to do with Windows 10. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: What video plugin are you using?

Comment: @DGarvanski Jabo's Direct3D8 1.7.0.57-ver5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since you're using Jabo's plugin there are several things you could try to fix this:

1. Revert to an older version of the plugin. The newer ones are known to, sometimes, cause flickering on Windows 10. (1.52 has been documented to work for some people)
2. Change the aspect ratio.
3. Use double buffering in the settings.

Comment: Thanks! I went to try Glide64 for PJ64: 2.0.0.1 and it worked without doing any setting adjustments!

Comment: Also, yes, completely changing the plugin is another fix.